# error - ReferenceError: Cannot access 'auth' before initialization

Tags: reactjs, next.js

so I am following this online tutorial on how to build a WhatsApp build and I ran into this problem.

```
 import "../styles/globals.css";
    import { useAuthState } from "react-firebase-hooks/auth";
    import { auth, db } from "../firebase";
    
    function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
      const [user] = useAuthState(auth);
    
      if (!user) return <Login />;
    
      return <Component {...pageProps} />;
    }
    
    export default MyApp;
```

This is my firebase.js, I removed the my apiKey because I am sharing my code but that don't think that is the issue.

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "global-chat-80ab3.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "global-chat-80ab3",
  storageBucket: "global-chat-80ab3.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "405392556419",
  appId: "1:405392556419:web:562d012b108561b8be76b6",
};

const app = !firebase.apps.length
  ? firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
  : firebase.app();

const db = app.firestore();
const auth = app.auth();
const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

export { db, auth, provider };
```

Comment: Does it tell you what line the error is coming from? Somewhere you are using `auth` when it doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using firebase v9 modular code as in firebase Documentation

Firebase Version: **9.6.1**

This code worked fine for me. But the downside I faced was v9 modular functionalities won't work with react-firebase-hooks.(Not supported till now I guess)

My usecase: for next.js project with firebase.

```
import { initializeApp, getApps } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { GoogleAuthProvider } from "firebase/auth";
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "global-chat-80ab3.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "global-chat-80ab3",
  storageBucket: "global-chat-80ab3.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "405392556419",
  appId: "1:405392556419:web:562d012b108561b8be76b6",
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = getApps().length === 0 ? initializeApp(firebaseConfig) : getApps();
const auth = getAuth();
const db = getFirestore();
const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();

export { db, auth, provider };
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're using Firebase 9.6.0, try updating your imports to v9 compat. This recommendation comes from the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade).

So, your imports would look like this:

```html
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "global-chat-80ab3.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "global-chat-80ab3",
  storageBucket: "global-chat-80ab3.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "405392556419",
  appId: "1:405392556419:web:562d012b108561b8be76b6",
};

const app = !firebase.apps.length
  ? firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
  : firebase.app();

const db = app.firestore();
const auth = app.auth();
const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

export { db, auth, provider };
```

Comment: 'compat' is for backwards compatibility when already implemented v8 without the need to migrate your whole application. So your solution is still basically V8